# Replace text everywhere within Yii application

Tags: yii, replace

I'd like to replace `--` string with `&mdash;` globally, everywhere within my Yii 1.x application (in every view, in strings generated by controllers or queried from database, everywhere).

What would be the best approach / solution to achieve this.

**EDIT**: I need to do this in the code, of course. It is not a question about, how to do this in the IDE, but using Yii.

Comment: If you are using an IDE like NetBeans, there is a tool for that. Go to `Edit` -> `Replace in Projects..`

Comment: No... :] I need to do this in the code, of course! :] It is not a question about IDE, but about programming...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use several ways. If you are not planning to set up i18n on your system you can handle it with Yii::t expression

```
    $result = Yii::t('common', 'May is a {{ rainy }} month', [
                '{{ rainy }}' => 'sunny',
    ]);
```

Otherwise, you can simply go with native PHP functions such as str_replace
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php and sprintf https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php

Comment: This is a nearly seven years old question, but somehow I still remember that I was asking here how to achieve it _in every view, in strings generated by controllers or queried from database, everywhere_. So the problem is not, how to perform actual replace (I know many ways for that), but how to propagate that? How to make sure that whatever comes out of your `$result` (or `str_replace`) result will be applied to every piece of string that comes out of Yii and goes back to browser / requesting client. So the question is more like about traversing entire output and replacing everything there.